# Created equations doesn't round correctly at the end

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written a coded equation as shown below,

```py
import numpy as np

hx_first_bracket = (1500 * np.pi / 60 ) ** 2
hx_second_bracket = (x[2] ** 4 / 4 - x[1] ** 4 / 4)
hx_final = (hx_first_bracket) * 2 * 10 ** -6 * np.pi * x[3] / Ef_x * (hx_second_bracket)

return hx_final
```

my issue is it prints the result -0.9196377239881504 but it should be -0.9196377239881505 as a result on tests to see if its correct I have already defined Ef_x in a previous equation and the x[] are np.array numbered positions. I have only used python for 4 weeks so i'm unsure if i'm missing any sort of NumPy constraints im using Python 3 in Jupyter not sure if the information is important

I have tried changing the brackets around and I have gotten a -0.9196377239881502 result but the 04 result is the closest i've gotten

Comment: Perhaps have a look into floating point math inaccuracies in a binary system.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? [What is the best way to compare floats for almost-equality in Python?](/q/5595425/4518341) See also [Is floating point math broken?](/q/588004/4518341)

Comment: The issue is the floating point inaccuracy is effecting multiple functions that would be using h(x) is there a way to possibly fix this?

Comment: You can use the [`decimal` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) to get higher precision, but it will be lots slower.

Comment: there are undefined variables in the example code.
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

computers generally have only 15 digits of precision for 64 bit floating point numbers ([Double](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)) which are used by the computers nowdays in calculations.

if you want more precision you have to use higher precision math library such as [mpmath](https://mpmath.org/doc/current/basics.html), also [sympy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) uses mpmath under the hood, so you should look into using either depending on your use case.

if you have a lot of computations and you want them to be done fast then use [gmpy](https://pypi.org/project/gmpy/) as it supports 128 bit floats, and is the fastest open-source implementation out there.

Comment: 64-bit floating point has 53 bits of precision, so it can usually achieve 16 decimal digits.  But that last decimal digit is always going to be iffy.

Comment: would there be any clashes with the np library if I used any of your suggestion as I need to exclusively use the np.array he's given me?

Comment: @Corro unfortunately yes, it will clash and you won't be able to use numpy arrays to store the results or the numbers will be truncated, sympy offers a similar matrix interface though, but it is obviously much slower than numpy.

Comment: @MarkRansom to be fair in my use-cases i saw only the first 14 digits after the decimal point were trusted across the entire range, his usecase is about the 16th digit after the decimal point so it is 2 digits too long.